# How to invert case of a string in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Good Day,
 I'm having a little difficulty getting how to convert a string to a inverse case. i.e

```
var Str = 'Hello World';
```

Then the Inverse Case of the above `Str` variable will be `hELLO wORLD`. I'm not sure how to achieve this;

I have the following (which is actually nothing, as i'm not sure how to go about it)

```
$('#inverse-case').on('click', function() {//When the button with id="inverse-case" is clicked
     var Text = $('#content').val(); //Get the value of the textarea with id="content"

     var newText = Text.replace(/[A-Z]/gi, /[a-z]/);          //This is the where i no longer know what to write (sorry, i'm a bit new to jQuery)

     $('#content').val(newText);//Then updated the textarea with id="content" with the Inverse transformed Case.
});
```

Thanks For your help in pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use a regular expression to check for alphabetical characters, and a callback function that replaces the character with its upper or lowercase equivalent:

```js
const str = 'Hello World';
const invertedStr = str.replace(
  /[a-z]/gi,
  char => /[a-z]/.test(char)
  ? char.toUpperCase()
  : char.toLowerCase()
);
console.log(invertedStr);
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked as expecting. now i see why the `regex` wasn't working. I was doing something like this `str.replace(/[A-Z]/gi, /[a-z]/)`. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

The @CertainPerformance answer is Ok. Another answer is following:

```
var str = "Hello World";
var invertStr = "";

for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    var ch = str.charAt(i);
    if (ch == ch.toUpperCase()) {
        invertStr += ch.toLowerCase() 
    }else{
        invertStr += ch.toUpperCase(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer... i'm testing out your answer

Comment: Works as well... Thanks @Mohammad Akbari